# Vertically, Center-fit an image inside a Table row '<tr>'

Tags: html, css

I need to center-fit a background image in a HTML Table row `<tr>`, the size of the image is 40px height and 10px width. Also I need to put a border around the background image, same with `border:2px solid #cccccc;`

The HTML is generated from Javascript so changes must be in CSS.

Here is how it looks:

**Rendered part of the page:**

http://snag.gy/4EYin.jpg

**Generated HTML:**

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
            <ul class="mystyle">
                <li>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
            <ul class="mystyle" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
                <li>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
.mystyle {
    border:2px solid #cccccc;
    background: url(../images/bar.png) no-repeat center left;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffe732', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 */
    width: 247px;       
}
```

**Update:**

The current image is almost good only that it have some unwanted "spaces" top and bottom.

Comment: `background-size:cover; background-position:center left; background-repeat:no-repeat;` Does this work?

Comment: It covers all the table row, i just need to vertically center-fit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>
.mystyle {
    border:2px solid #cccccc;
    background: url(bar.png) no-repeat center left;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffe732', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 */
    width: 247px; 
    background-position:center;      
}
</style>
```